# Bigfoot: make sans serif footnote

Tags: sans-serif, bigfoot

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bigfoot}

\newfootnote[plain]{default}
\begin{document}
Hello\footnote{A totally cool footnote} world!
\end{document}
```

The footnote apperas in a serif font, I'd rather like to get a sans serif font.

Comment: I have no clue where to start. The bigfoot/manyfoot documentation is not really advertising how to change the font shape...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution with `xpatch`. If you don't want the footnote number to be typed in a sans font, remove the second patch:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bigfoot}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\newfootnote[plain]{default}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@makefnstartbox}{%
\footnotesize}%
{\footnotesize\sffamily}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\@makefnmark}{\normalfont}{\sffamily}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\vspace*{0.9\textheight}
Hello\footnote{A totally cool footnote. } world!

\end{document}
```

[image]